# Sikuli @ Sign with java

Tags: java, keyboard, sikuli

I have a string for my email-address:

```
 String email = "dummy@web.de";
```

Now I want to type this email-address to a certain field on a web page. So I do this

```
 s.type("login.png", email);
```

but if I execute the application this will be typed

**dummy"web.de**

I have a **german** keyboard layout and on german keyboards the @-symbol is located on <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. So I modified the application like this

```
s.click("login.png");
s.type("dummy");
s.keyDown(KeyModifier.ALTGR);
s.type("q");
s.keyUp(KeyModifier.ALTGR);
```

and the result is "dummy q" (with a space)

I also tried this

```
s.type("q", KeyModifier.ALTGR);
```

but this will result in "dummyq" (without a space)

In case somebody needs this information, I use the following imports:

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;
import org.sikuli.basics.Debug;
```

and I use sikulixapi-1.1.0.jar

Thanks for your help
Hauke

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself. In order somebody has the same issue

```
s.type("q", KeyModifier.ALT | KeyModifier.CTRL);
```

this fixed the problem.

Comment: old bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/511740 you can also apparantly workaround by using `paste()` (and I guess copying the text you need to clipboard before that).